# Java string error

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I'm trying to solve the following problem however it won't compute after values are entered. I am hoping this could be corrected quickly and haven't got the if-else statements wrong? Thanks!

*Write a method named season that takes as parameters two integers representing a month number and a day number, and returns a String that indicates the season for that month and day. Assume that the month is speciﬁed as an integer between 1 and 12 (1 for January, 2 for February, and so on), and that the day of the month is a number between 1 and 31.
If the date falls between 12/16 and 3/15, you should return "Winter". If the date falls between 3/16 and 6/15, you should return "Spring". If the date falls between 6/16 and 9/15, you should return "Summer". And if the date falls between 9/16 and 12/15, you should return "Fall"."*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Seasons
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("This program reports the season for a given day and month");
 System.out.print("Please enter the month and day as integers with a space between the month and day:");
 int month = keyboard.nextInt();
 int day = keyboard.nextInt();
 }

public static String season(int month, int day)

{

if ((month == 12 && day >= 16) || (month == 3 || day <= 15) || (month == 1 || month == 2))
return "Winter";

if ((month == 3 && day >= 16) || (month == 6 || day <= 15) || (month == 4 || month == 5))
return "Spring";

if ((month == 6 && day >= 16) || (month == 9 || day <= 15) || (month == 7 || month == 8))
return "Summer";

if ((month == 9 && day >= 16) || (month == 12 || day <= 15) || (month == 10 || month == 11))
return "Fall";

else
  {
     return "impossible!";
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You never invoke your `season` method. Add the line `String result = season(month, day);` in your main after you got the values from the user, and print this result in your console. Also you should rework your conditions, if `month = 50` and `day = 2`, it will output winter.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the method `season` yet.

Add the line:

```
System.out.println(Seasons.season(month, day));
```

to the end of the `main` method. This will call the method and print its return value.

You might even be able to improve your solution:
Have you already thought about input validation? What if the user enters `Monday`? Or numbers that are too large?

Answer (score 0):

you are not calling season method anywhere.As season is a static method so you need not create an object.Call methods like this format `classname.staticmethod()`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Seasons
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("This program reports the season for a given day and month");
 System.out.print("Please enter the month and day as integers with a space between the month and day:");
 int month = keyboard.nextInt();
 int day = keyboard.nextInt();
String result=Seasons.season(month,day)
System.out.println(result);
 }

public static String season(int month, int day)

{

if ((month == 12 && day >= 16) || (month == 3 || day <= 15) || (month == 1 || month == 2))
return "Winter";

if ((month == 3 && day >= 16) || (month == 6 || day <= 15) || (month == 4 || month == 5))
return "Spring";

if ((month == 6 && day >= 16) || (month == 9 || day <= 15) || (month == 7 || month == 8))
return "Summer";

if ((month == 9 && day >= 16) || (month == 12 || day <= 15) || (month == 10 || month == 11))
return "Fall";

else
  {
     return "impossible!";
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

...

    public static String season(int month, int day){
        Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
        int year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if(inBetween(year, 3, 16, year, 6, 15, year, month, day))
            return "Spring";
        else if(inBetween(year, 6, 16, year, 9, 15, year, month, day))
            return "Summer";
        else if(inBetween(year, 9, 16, year, 12, 15, year, month, day))
            return "Fall";
        else if(inBetween(year, 12, 16, year,  12, 31, year,   month, day)||
                inBetween(year+1,1,  1, year+1, 3, 15, year+1, month, day))
            return "Winter";
        return "impossible";
    }
    public static boolean inBetween(int startY, int startM, int startD,
                                    int endY,   int endM,   int endD,
                                    int year,   int month,  int day){
            Calendar startDay = new GregorianCalendar();
            startDay.clear();
            startDay.set(startY, startM-1, startD);
            Calendar endDay = new GregorianCalendar();
            endDay.clear();
            endDay.set(endY, endM-1, endD);
            Calendar checkDay = new GregorianCalendar();
            checkDay.clear();
            checkDay.set(year, month-1, day);
            //startDay <= checkDay && checkDay <= endDay
            return startDay.compareTo(checkDay)<=0 && checkDay.compareTo(endDay)<=0;
    }
```

Comment: Needs to be checked further date if you do not allow 4 50.

Comment: -1 because it is over-engineered and and just providing a lot of code without any description will not help anyone learn.

Comment: @NickJ It is just a simple example of using the GregorianCalendar and  Calendar. LOL.